# How to check param route in router

Tags: vuejs3, vue-router, vue-composition-api

How can I check a param of a route from a variable like so:

```
const SUB_ROUTES = {
    GLOBALSTAR: "globalStar",
    PARKINGMULTIPEAJE: "parkingMultipeaje",
    RESERVAS: "reservas",
};
```

then in the router.ts file check someDomain.com/route/subRoute where subRoute exists inside SUB_ROUTES otherwise being redirected to notFound

Comment: Define your route like `{path: '/pathname/:parameterName', name: 'MyCustomRoute', component: .....,}` - then in your component you will be able to check the parameter like `this.$route.params.parameterName`

Answer (score 0):

I manage to solve it using per route guards from the [vue docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#Per-Route-Guard) and redirecting to NotFound.vue component like this:

```
            {
                path: "/mapas/:maptype",
                name: "MapsClientes",
                component: Mapas,
                props: true,
                beforeEnter: (to, from) => {
                    if (!Object.values(MAP_TYPE).includes(to.params.maptype as string)) router.push({ name: "NoEncontrado" });
                }
            }
```